# Flask: How to avoid slow, multiple imports?

Tags: flask

I have a Flask application consisting of several blueprints, each residing in its own module. After deploying the app (using Apache), I find that for each blueprint it takes several seconds to respond for the first time. It is my impression that this has to do with importing pretty heavy packages in the blueprints (sqlalchemy in each blueprint, and pandas / matplotlib in some).

Is there some way to do all the imports only once for the whole app?

Or maybe I'm way off track here and the first-time-slow effect comes from something else?

[EDIT]

I'm using mod_wsgi configured like this:

```
WSGIScriptReloading On
WSGIDaemonProcess   wsgi processes=4 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP}
WSGIProcessGroup    wsgi
WSGIScriptAlias     /dham     /var/www/wsgi/dham.wsgi
```

I've found a workaround by adding this nop() function to each of my blueprints, and have a script call all those targets upon deploying.

```
@blp.route("/nop")
def nop():
    return flask.render_template_string("")
```

Below is the restart script. It takes about four seconds for each target, but when I run the same thing w/o killing WSGI first, the time spent is virtually zero.

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Killing wsgi subprocesses"
ps ax | \
    sed -nr 's/([0-9]+).*\(wsgi:wsgi\).*/kill -KILL \1/p' |\
    sudo /bin/sh
unset http_proxy

for target in doklink procontrol jobwatch admin tagestest spc; do
    curl http://localhost/dham/$target/nop > /dev/null
done
```

Comment: How are you deploying "using Apache"?  mod_wsgi?  Or running a different wsgi worker behind an Apache reverse proxy?

Comment: @imichaeldotorg: Thanks for asking, see my edit for clarification

Answer (score 0):

I found out that Flask doesn't import the same package separately for each blueprint. Rather I found that different blueprints start in different processes. If I force WSGI to run in one process only there is only one long load time.